# Combining Multiple CSV files with Python

Tags: python, pandas, csv, concatenation, cwd

I am trying to combine multiple csv files into 1 csv file in a python script.  I want to skip writing the first 5 lines of each csv file.  Having some trouble and I am new to Python.  I have tried several examples that I have found but it seems to have trouble with the working directory.  Here is my latest attempt:

```
import pandas as pd
import csv
import glob
import os

path = '//server01/tmp/'
files_in_dir = [f for f in os.listdir(path) if f.endswith('csv')]
count = 0
for filenames in files_in_dir:
    df = pd.read_csv(filenames)
    if count < 6:
            count += 1
            continue
    df.to_csv('out.csv', mode='a')
```

Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: hmm you want to combine the data frames right. when you do pd.read_csv it reads in the whole chunk. So the count doesn't work.

Comment: Does `read_csv()` work if you read the whole thing, or do those first 5 lines break it?  If the former, you can just read the CSV and omit those 5 lines when appending to a master dataframe.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
import pandas as pd
import csv
import glob
import os

path = '//server01/tmp/'
files_in_dir = [os.path.join(path,f) for f in os.listdir(path) if f.endswith('csv')]
for filenames in files_in_dir:
    df = pd.read_csv(filenames, skiprows = 5)
    df.to_csv('out.csv', mode='a')
```

**skiprows**: number of lines to skip

**nrows**: number of rows of file to read